# BootstrapValidator and ComboBox Validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, combobox

i am trying to validate form using http://bootstrapvalidator.com/, regular control works fine but for combobox control from https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox I am unable to show the validation message.

HTML:

```
<form id="frmVisaForm" name="frmVisaForm" class="horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group"> <span class="help-block span-required">Place of Issue</span>

        <select id="cmbApplicantPassportPlace" name="cmbApplicantPassportPlace" class="form-control combobox" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Jaipur</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group"> <span class="help-block span-required">Country of Issue</span>

        <select id="cmbApplicantPassportCountry" name="cmbApplicantPassportCountry" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Delhi">India</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Nepal</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.combobox').combobox();
    $('#frmVisaForm').bootstrapValidator({

        submitHandler: function (validator, form, submitButton) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sudiptabanerjee/b5MG9/

Need help, please.

Best Regards
Sudipta Banerjee

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with that. Have you found out the solution??

Comment: No I couldn't find the solution. We have removed bootstrap-combobox.

Answer (score 1):

> To force a user to select an option from a select box, provide an empty options like
>
> **value=""**>Choose...

```
 <select class="form-control col-md-3" name="guests">
                                            <option value="">--No of Guests--</option>
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                            <option>5</option>
                                        </select>
```